# How to derive this Hankel's Contour integral formula with gamma function?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

This relation was put up in The Art Of Computer Programming and no derivation was offered. Please help me understand this better.

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma (z)} = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint\frac{e^t dt}{t^z}$$

It said that the path of the complex integration starts at $-\infty$ circles around the origin and returns to $-\infty$.

If not a derivation, at least help me develop some intuition about this. How are we introducing complex analysis to a function that came up in the real numbers ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, i don't want to be a jerk, so here we go. Let's define the complex valued function

$$
f(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{z^x}
$$

We integrate $f(z)$ over the so called Hankel contour $\mathcal{H}$ which consists of three parts ($\delta \rightarrow 0_+$):

-the line segment $[-\infty+i\delta,i\delta]$, denoted by $l_+$

-a small semicircle around the origin with radius $\delta$, denoted by $sc$

-the line segment $[-\infty-i\delta,-i\delta]$, denoted by $l_-$

Note that this contour fixes the branch cut of log to lie on the negative real axis.

It is not difficult to show that $\int_{sc}f(z)dz$ yields a zero contribution as long as $z>-1$ so we end up,using Cauchy's integral theorem, with

$$
\int_{\mathcal{H}} f(z)dz=-\int_{l+}f(z)dz-\int_{l-}f(z)dz
$$

now noting that $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}f(t\pm i\delta)=e^{\mp i \pi x }\frac{e^{t}}{|t|^x}$ we obtain

$$
\int_{\mathcal{H}}  f(z)dz =2i\sin(\pi x)\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^t}{|t|^x}dt=2i\sin(\pi x)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t^x}dt
$$

the last integral is the standard integral representation of the gamma function

$$
\int_{\mathcal{H}}  f(z)dz=2i \sin(\pi x)\Gamma(1-x)
$$

thanks to the [well known multiplicative property of the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) this equals

> $$
> \int_{\mathcal{H}}  f(z)dz=\frac{2i\pi}{\Gamma(x)} 
> $$
>   **QED**

Comment: Very well done!  I wish I could vote geater than +1.

Comment: thanks @Dr.MV, much appreciated! But i'm sure you can at least award me with a simple +1  (guess you just forgot it!). ;)

Comment: @Dr.MV Did you vote ? I don't see any upvotes

Comment: @tired Can you tell me what background knowledge is necessary to understand your proof ? I'm having difficulties in understanding it.

Comment: what is your background in complex analysis? You should know about things like contour integration, branch cuts and basic properties of the gamma function.

Comment: I am working from a "not-so-smart-phone," and it appeared as though my upvote was recorded.  I've tried again.  Let me know if it appears now.  -Mark

Comment: @tired I know some properties of Gamma function but not that much about contour integration and branch cuts.

Comment: Mark, your smartphone seems to be capable to learn! thanks again!

Comment: @user230452 then i would recommend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration for starters

Comment: @tired Thanks. I'll definitely look at it !

Comment: @tired Hey, thanks a lot ! I'm actually understanding a lot from this page (unlike when I tried self studying it from books).

Comment: @user230452 happy to hear that!

Comment: Hi, I have another question about contour integration here. I think you can help me. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1847350/230452

Comment: I don't understand why $$lim_{δ→0}f(t±iδ)=e^{∓iπx}\frac{e^t}{|t|^x}$$

Comment: @tired Also shouldn't it be $$∫_{H}f(z)dz=−∫_{l+}f(z)dz+∫_{l−}f(z)dz$$ instead?

Comment: @Horus for the standard branch of log this is what happens...