# Application of complex analysis and contour integral in generating functions

Tags: complex-analysis, generating-functions, contour-integration

Normally generating functions are tools of discrete mathematics and integrals deal with continuous structures. A book offered the following formula without much explanation and I'm not able to understand it.

$$[z^n]G(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r} \frac{G(z)dz}{z^{n+1}}$$
$G(z)$ converges for $z = z_0$ and $0 \lt r\lt |z_0|$. 
From the denominator, I see that Cauchy's formula has been used. But, I don't see how to use it in generating functions. My main question is how can Cauchy's formula help in extracting a coefficient ? Please offer some exposition.

Comment: Plug in the Taylorseries for $G(z)$ 

$$
\oint  \frac{a_0+a_1z+...a_n z^n+...}{z^{n+1}}
$$

using Cauchy this equals

$$
2 \pi i a_n
$$

Comment: @tired If you could just expand a little bit on this and post it as an answer, I would appreciate it. (It's also easier for me to read LaTeX on answers than comments on my tablet.) I'll probably accept it too.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

$G(z)=g_{0}+g_{1}z+g_{2}z^{2}+\ldots$

If you take the $n$th derivative of $G(z)$ and evaluate it at $z=0$, you get $n!$ times the coefficient $g_{n}$.  Thus evaluating derivatives of $G(z)$ at $z=0$ is a way to get at the coefficients $g_{n}$.

For example,

$G'''(z)=6g_{3}+24g_{4}z+60g_{5}z^{2}+\ldots$

and $G'''(0)=6g_{3}$.

The formula given in your question is simply Cauchy's formula for evaluating the $n$th derivative of $G(z)$ at $z=0$ (with the factor of $n!$ taken care of.)

Comment: I understood your point about taking derivatives at $z=0$ to get coefficients but didn't unddrstand how Cauchys formula relates to this. Also isn't integration the inverse process of differentiation?

Answer (score 0):

This integral is also known as the *inverse Z-transform* of a generating function. You can search more on this topic to find additional proofs and techniques in Fourier analysis for evaluating this integral.